# Adafruit_Arcada' does not name a type;

Tags: library, adafruit

I am trying to program an adafruit pygamer (which says it's compatible with Arduino). I have added the ZIP folder for the library into the library folder om my PC where all of my folders are supposed to be stored, one thing I managed to find out for a start was that the library folder for the library itself that was installed from GitHub contained a dash in the filename so I replaced that for an underscore. The actual error message that seems to come up now is this:

```
'Adafruit_Arcada' does not name a type; did you mean 'Adafruit_SPITFT'?
```

This error comes up from when I try to use the:

```
#include "Adafruit_Arcada.h"

Adafruit_Arcada arcada;
```

lines

Within the library folder that I want to try and use there are the code examples within the library folder inside the examples sub-folder

I have tried following a step by step guide into one potential way of trying to solve this problem by looking at a tutorial by adafruit on how to step by step install zip folder libraries. Something tells me though that this error that I am getting is to do with one of the .h or .cpp files within the library itself.

The link for the library itself is here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Arcada

In addition, when I look in the `Adafruit_Arcada.h` file I can actually see that there is no `Adafruit_Arcada` class but there is an `Adafruit_SPITFT` one. I know this point might seem like a bit of a no-brainer but I just thought it would be useful to try and find out what could potentially be going on and provide evidence of what I have already tried to do.

When I changed the `Adafruit_Arcada arcada;` to `Adafruit_SPITFT arcada;` (thinking this could potentially resolve the issue because within the `Adafruit_Arcada.h` file there is a class called `Adafruit_SPITFT and not`Adafruit_Arcada`), this brought up another error which was the following:

```
simpletest:2:17: error: no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_SPITFT::Adafruit_SPITFT()'
```

Comment: The `Adafruit_Arcada` class is defined in `Boards/Adafruit_Arcada_PyGamer.h` and inherits from the `Adafruit_Arcada_SPITFT` class. I guess there are specific versions of the class for each board.

Comment: @chrisl So what classes would I need to mention within my code in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are some instructions at:

[Pygamer setup](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pygamer/setup)

That need to be followed in order to permit the Arduino IDE to work with the Pygamer.  It's not clear that you have followed any or all of these instructions.

I recommend that you carefully follow ALL the steps and then start with the simple example to test that you are building and uploading properly.

Then move on to the Adafruit example that uses the Arcada library.

Comment: So what I have done is followed all of the instructions in the link sent and the board not has its own serial COM port and does work with a very basic blink example program which does not include any libraries at all. the error to do with ```Adafruit_Arcada' does not name a type;```. The next problem occuring is that now another error message is coming up within the code which I am not too sure it is trying to say:

Comment: ```Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_EPD\src\Adafruit_EPD.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_EPD::csHigh()':```
and                                                        ```libraries\Adafruit_EPD\src\Adafruit_EPD.cpp:649:12: error: 'class Adafruit_SPIDevice' has no member named 'endTransaction'.```

Comment: Something is telling me that something is either out of date or I might have potentially installed something wrong because in the guide that was sent there is 5 examples within the adafruit arcada library. But with the one I have installed, there is lots of examples. The guide itself was not updated too long ago. The arcada library I have installed is the one installed from the library manger and the version of the library is 2.5.0. Perhaps the library is too update to date compared to the one in the guide which potentially might be more out of date.